# mysql get a LIMIT only count for 1 table in left-join

Tags: mysql, database, left-join

I use the following query to get info out of my database:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles v LEFT JOIN pictures f ON f.vehicles_id = v.id WHERE v.visible = 0";
```

My database looks like this:

vehicles:

```
+----------+--------------+
|  id      | name         | 
+----------+--------------+
| 1        | johanalj     | 
| 2        | hjgjhggjh    | 
+----------+--------------+
```

images of the vehicles:

```
+----------+--------------+----------------+
|  id      | url          | vehicles_ID    |
+----------+--------------+----------------+
| 1        | 3765345.png  | 1              |
| 2        | 87e58974.png | 1              |
| 3        | e5e974.png   | 1              |
| 4        | 3455345.png  | 2              |
| 5        | 88974.png    | 2              |
| 6        | e5e974.png   | 3              |
+----------+--------------+----------------+
```

This works fine. Now the problem is I want to add a limit so that only 2 vehicles get selected. So I tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles v LEFT JOIN pictures f ON f.vehicles_id = v.id WHERE v.visible = 0 LIMIT 2";
```

But instead of only 2 vehicles it selects the first vehicle and the first picture attached to it. Now how can I get the query use the limit on the vehicles table only?

Hope anyone can help me out!

Great thanx in advance

Comment: You don't have visible column in your db description. At least I don't see it. Furthermore, maybe you only have one result.

Comment: My bad. forgot to add that one in. The answer below helped me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM vehicles
  WHERE visible = 0 
  LIMIT 2
) v 
LEFT JOIN pictures f ON f.vehicles_id = v.id
```